# Indexing sunspot records for testing in minitest (StubSessionProxy errors)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I test a lot of sunpot's functionality in my tests but lately I've been getting a lot of errors in my testing.

The error I've been getting in nearly all my tests with sunspot functionality:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method config for #<Sunspot::Rails::StubSessionProxy:0x0055695c4d5768>
```

I've been reindexing my models in many of my tests in the setup method:

```
def setup
  Model.reindex
end
```

When I run a single test file individually, everything seems to work. If I try to run the whole test directory at once, I get many StubSessionProxy errors in all of the tests which reindex a model.

Should I not be reindexing that way in my testing? If I don't reindex, then the sunspot functionality doesn't work in my tests.

Can anyone shed light on what I'm doing wrong?